# EF Core - part of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is not known

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I have defined a composite key, where one of the properties is the Id of the table and is auto-generated by the database. The other field in the relationship is the foreign key of a related table.

For example:

```
public class State
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }

   public ICollection<City> Cities{ get; set; }
}

public class City
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public int StateId { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey(nameof(StateId))]
   public State State { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

In model builder, I have specified:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<City> builder)
{            
   builder.HasKey(x => new { x.Id, x.StateId });
}
```

This works greate if I am adding a city to a state. This is presumably because the state already has an Id. But if I am creating a new state and trying to add a city at the same time, I get the following error:

System.InvalidOperationException: The value of 'City.StateId' is unknown when attempting to save changes. This is because the property is also part of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is not known.

I have been doing a lot of reading and trying to figure out how to maintain the composite key and specify the principal entity. For my purposes, the compsite key is required.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:
Post Method

```
public virtual async Task<ActionResult<V>> Add(V viewModel)
{
    var _mapped = _mapper.Map<V, T>(viewModel);
    _service.Create(_mapped);
    await _service.SaveAsync();

    return Ok(viewModel);
}

public void Create(T entity)
{
    this._dbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `[Key]` **and** `HasKey()`? Use one or the other, not both.

Comment: Ok, I didn't think it would matter. I think I used HasKey to create a composite key on the city table. So City.Id and City.StateId is the primary key of the City table. City.StateId is also a foreign key.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code you're using to actually add the entities to your dbcontext? Depending on how you establish the FK relationship (i.e. defining the one-to-many or the many-to-one in your context) EF can be finnicky with the order of access entities.

Comment: @broccoli_rob, I'm not sure if I completely understand your comment, but I edited my original post to show the Post method which user AutoMapper to map from ViewModel to Model.

Comment: So in that example, **viewModel** is a state with one or more cities, or is it a city with the ```State``` property set to a new state? The order likely matters because EF will try to save the primary instance first. 

Something that might help is to add ```"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Information"``` in the Logging section of your appsettings.json file and view the generated SQL in your output to be sure of the order of operations.

Comment: It is a State Viewmodel which contains a list of Cities.

Comment: The composite key `{ x.Id, x.StateId }` makes no sense, since the `x.Id` is unique by itself and uniquely identifies the record, so the second column has no effect on uniqueness. Thus is useless, does not give any functionality and just cause problems. In standard relational design such entity would have primary key `Id` (with unique index) and foreign key `StateId` with non unique index. This is what EF Core will create for you without any attribute/fluent API interventions from your side.

Comment: Hello Ivan. I understand what you are saying and in most cases, I would agree with you. But as I said, it is required in our case. We have a Generic history tracking algorithm that uses the primary key of each table to identify changes that are made by users. If a user adds a city, deletes a City, or modifies a City, we need to be able to track that. It looks at each field that has a property of primary key. It ignores foreign keys. Thus for many to many relationships, it works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar issue in my tests and after some debugging and investigation, my fault was that I was assigning the Primary Key myself, instead of letting EF do it.

In your case, it would mean that you assign the State.Id property somewhere in your code before saving it to the Db. Which is possible, but it seems to confuse EF when trying to compose the composite key with the StateId value, because for EF this value doesn't exist yet.

These are my models and modelbuilder setup:

```
public class Ledger
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Code { get; set; } = null!;
     public List<Article> Articles { get; set; } = new();
 }

 public class Article
 {
     public int LedgerId { get; set; }
     public Ledger Ledger{ get; set; } = new();
     public string Code { get; set; } = null!;
     public bool Active { get; set; }
     public DateTime? CancelDate { get; set; }
     public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
 }

 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Ledger>(builder =>
    {
        builder.ToTable("Ledger")
            .HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder
            .Property(p => p.Code)
            .HasColumnName("Code");

        builder
            .HasMany(x => x.Articles)
            .WithOne(article => article.Ledger)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.LedgerId);
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Article>(builder =>
    {
        builder.ToTable("Article")
            .HasKey(x => new { x.Code, x.LedgerId });
    });
 }
```

And this is what I was doing in my tests:

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetLedgerQueryHandler_Handle_Found()
{
    //Arrange
    _dbContext.Ledger.AddRange(
        new Ledger { Id = 1, Code = "C1", Articles = new List<Article> { new Article { Code = "AC1"} } },
        new Ledger { Id = 2, Code = "C2"} );
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();

    //Act
    var result = await _ledgerQueryHandler.Handle(new GetLedgerQuery("C1"), CancellationToken.None);

    //Assert
    result.Should().NotBeNull();
    result!.Series.Should().NotBeNull().And.NotBeEmpty();
}
```

The problem here was the **Id = 1** and **Id = 2** assignments on the Ledger class. EF can fill this property in itself, because it is the PK. But because I  am assigning it myself, the composite key seems to have trouble finding the value of the Id and throwing this error since it thinks it's not assigned.

After removing those assignments, everything works as expected.

Working code:

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetLedgerQueryHandler_Handle_Found()
{
    //Arrange
    _dbContext.Ledger.AddRange(
        new Ledger { Code = "C1", Articles = new List<Article> { new Article { Code = "AC1"} } },
        new Ledger { Code = "C2"} );
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();

    //Act
    var result = await _ledgerQueryHandler.Handle(new GetLedgerQuery("C1"), CancellationToken.None);

    //Assert
    result.Should().NotBeNull();
    result!.Series.Should().NotBeNull().And.NotBeEmpty();
}
```

Hope this is helps.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. That all makes perfect sense. We all decided to go in a different direction and not use the composite key and everything works well for us now, but should the need arise in the future, I will keep this in mind. Thank you for taking the time to respond.